# Can't download iTunes

Tags: itunes, windows, data-transfer, firefox, websites

I wish to download iTunes to my MS Windows (Windows 7 Home Premium, 64-bit) computer. So I surf to [`http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/`](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/) and discover a "Download iTunes" header. Beneath it is
[image: a set of options for receiving e-mail, and a "Download Now" button.]

I fill in the options, click "Download Now", and a dialog box opens asking me whether to download the file or to cancel. I choose to download it (and where to save it to), even as the browser surfs to a confirmation ("Now that you’ve downloaded iTunes") page. The dialog box closes, and nothing gets downloaded. The browser's "Downloads" window does not show that any attempt to download a file from Apple had been made.

1. What gives? I mean, what's going on here? Why can't I download iTunes?
2. Does anyone have a solution, or at least a workaround, please?

---

I've tried this also from [`https://`](https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/): also no dice. I'm doing this on Firefox 21.0, both in usual and in "Private Browsing" modes.

Comment: Did you tried to download it from IE ?

Comment: Are you able to download files from other websites?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler, no. I did try `curl` but apparently it's not installed. I'm afraid that, if I run IE, Microsoft will change my settings so IE is the default browser or something. Just kidding. Sort of. Honestly, I typed `internet explorer` into the blank space bar on the "Start" menu, but there were no search results, so I'm guessing I don't have IE (though I didn't think that was possible on Windows). I don't want to install a whole new browser (especially not IE!) just to get iTunes, though I can if necessary; I was hoping for some other solution.

Comment: @Elliott, I am.

Comment: Strange--I have the same problem. When I did it from IE, it worked. Never had that before!

Answer (score 2):

Apple doesn't have a downloads page to directly download iTunes - and the link typically goes to a content delivery network.

In june, you could temporarily try downloading from https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/iTunes11/091-6059.20130605.205Rf/iTunesSetup.exe but this URL will likely change or fail in the near future. In September, the link is now https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/iTunes11/041-8597.20130918.PmmEw/iTunesSetup.exe so you can see trying to pass around direct links is not a good general solution.

The best thing to do in this case is check that you don't have any DNS blockers or other web site plug in that attempt to control / restrict downloads and try refreshing that page (or try in another browser).

Apple support might also be a good place to open a ticket, since they usually support people looking to use iTunes or Apple ID for free since you can't spend money with them without these accounts and tools.

Other things to try:

- Change your network (have a friend download the file from a different router / internet connection) and share it over Dropbox or other means - this would fix DNS issues or other network effects.
- Change your browser - if Chrome or Firefox have add-ons, blockers, etc. - try disabling all browser scripts and extensions or even another browser like Opera or Lynx or Safari
- Change your computer - downloading from another computer might show the problem is with DNS settings or something else specific to your PC.

Comment: I had the same problem with no download occurring. The link shown worked yesterday. However, it downloaded an older version than I already had, not the latest version.

Comment: That is exactly the problem with deeply linking to just one file. Those links are fragile, not maintained and possibly out dated ten seconds after we document them.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't download iTunes Windows 7 64 bit from Firefox 25.0.1, but had no problem when I used IE 11.  There must be some setting in Firefox that prevents the download such as if you use private browsing mode.

Comment: This worked for me, but this situation is ridiculous. I have the same issue from Firefox 35 and Chrome 39 on Win 7 64-bit. Web page says "Thank you for downloading iTunes" but the download never even started. IE 10 worked. How hard is it to download a file, seriously?

Comment: This also works for me in IE. I tried Safari and Chrome on Mac, then I tried Chrome on Windows, then after reading this I tried IE.  IE worked.

Answer (score 0):

What is odd is that today the itunes "check for updates and install" worked normally. I had tried this multiple times over several days before with the same failed results of the OP.

For those with the problem of the OP, it sounds like one possible fix is to give your machine a couple of (virtual) aspirins and a few days rest, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **Control Panel** → **User Accounts** → **Change User Account Control Settings**.
2. Change to **Never Notify** or the one above.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you close your itunes before attempting the download. this simple step worked for me.